# SQL syntax error 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to upload this file to netbeans however I am unable to create the authors table and continue to receive the following error:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
   authorID INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   firstName varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   lastName varchar (30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (authorID)
);

INSERT INTO authors (firstName, lastName)
VALUES 
   ('Paul','Deitel'), 
   ('Harvey','Deitel'),
   ('Abbey','Deitel'), 
   ('Dan','Quirk'),
   ('Michael','Morgano');
```

**[Warning, Error code 1,064, SQLState 42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   firstName varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   lastName va' at line 2**

**[Exception, Error code 1,064, SQLState 42000] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   firstName varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   lastName va' at line 2
Line 2, column 1**

**[Warning, Error code 1,146, SQLState 42S02] Table 'books.authors' doesn't exist**

I have been searching all over the web for hours and have yet to find an answer! I am new to SQL so I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I am using MYSQL version 5.7.18

Answer (score 11):

There are seval things wrong:

1. `identity` is SQL Server syntax, MySQL uses `auto_increment`
2. `<name> <type> generated always as <calculation>` applies to calculated columns.

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE authors (
   authorID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   firstName varchar (20) NOT NULL,
   lastName varchar (30) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (authorID)
);
```

Comment: Actually, `identity(1,1)` is SQL Server. `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` is ANSI, which is supported by recent versions of PostgreSQL and Oracle, and _not_ SQL Server.