# Getting syntax error during CASE WHEN query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, jboss, db2

I am trying to run below small MYSQL query to create a table .

This is the MYSQL query :

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TEST (
  ID BIGINT ,
  TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
  TYPE2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN TYPE = 0 THEN ID ELSE TYPE END),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  );
```

After running the above query , i am getting following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN TYPE = 0 THEN ID ELSE TYPE END),
  PRIMARY KEY (I' at line 4
```

I was using `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` in `DB2` database and i have changed to `auto_increment`  from [SQL syntax error 'GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965114/sql-syntax-error-generated-always-as-identity) ?

Now i want to know whether `CASE WHEN` is present in MySQL or any alternative for MySQL ?  Any help or suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use datatype before using GENERATED ALWAYS. 
U can use below code with the datatype which is needed.

```
CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TEST (
    ID BIGINT,
    TYPE INTEGER NOT NULL,
    TYPE2 DOUBLE GENERATED ALWAYS AS
        (CASE WHEN `TYPE` = 0 THEN `ID` ELSE `TYPE` END),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

As per MySQL documentation, you need to follow the below syntax

col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression)

so,

```
TYPE2 INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN TYPE = 0 THEN ID ELSE TYPE END) should work
```

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html